# How can I setup sign in as Google account on a react native + asp core web api and Identity server as middleware

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

How can I configure my mobile app project to sign in using external providers (Google). I am using react native + web api core. Most examples using google sign in is using ASP.Net Web application not web Api. I am using also Identity server as middleware

Answer (score 0):

IDS4 still requires a serverside UI (although you could in theory use whatever client side framework you wish) so to keep things simple I'd wire the Google sign into your existing sign in UI flow.

For a native app it's strongly recommended that you use the authorization code flow with PKCE and use ASWebAuthenticationSession or custom tabs for iOS and Android respectively.

Comment: yeah, I think I won't be needing IDS4 in my case. I will just tap on google sign in integrations on the UI and I think I'll have to do some sort of configurations on the web api for that part also

Comment: and also what google api can be used for hybrid mobile app